# How to retrieve data using EF Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a console application. I'm trying to use EF Database First. I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model, then EF Designer from Database. Then I connected to the database, and classes are generated. Now what should I do to retrieve the data of these classes? Here is my empty Program.cs file :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of examples that you can find if you search google.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx). There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Here are the example for all approaches http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing you a sample code.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
    { 
        // Create and save a new Blog 
        Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: "); 
        var name = Console.ReadLine(); 

        var blog = new Blog { Name = name }; 
        db.Blogs.Add(blog); 
        db.SaveChanges(); 

        // Display all Blogs from the database 
        var query = from b in db.Blogs 
                    orderby b.Name 
                    select b; 

        Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:"); 
        foreach (var item in query) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name); 
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..."); 
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 
}
```

BloggingContext is my context and Blog is my table name.